# Creating a data structure in python for use in a Jinja2 template

Tags: python, html, csv, jinja2

I would like to use python to read in CSV data and then output it using Jinja2 to make a flat file HTML report. The CSV data that I would like to use is as follows:

```
State,City,Issue,Date
Michigan,Detroit,Economic Issues,12/11/14
Michigan,Detroit,Poor Schools,12/11/14
Michigan,Battle Creek,Economic Issues,2/12/14
Georgia,Atlanta,Lack of Transit,2/12/14
Georgia,Atlanta,Traffic,2/12/14
Georgia,Cummings,Economic Issues,12/11/14
Georgia,Cummings,Poor Schools,12/11/14
Georgia,Athens,Traffic,12/11/14
Florida,Miami,Weather Issues,12/11/14
Florida,Miami,Poor Schools,2/12/14
Florida,Miami,Economic Issues,2/12/14
Florida,Miami,Lack of Transit,2/12/14
Florida,Sarasota,Economic Issues,2/12/14
Florida,Levy,Poor Schools,2/12/14
Florida,Lee,Traffic,2/12/14
California,Los Angeles,Traffic,12/11/14
Alaska,Anchorage,Weather Issues,2/12/14
```

I would like to have the one row for each state that then has each city under it along with the associated Issue and Date.

The output would be similar to this:

```
Michigan
        Detroit        Economic Issues        12/11/2014
                       Poor Schools           12/11/2014
        Battle Creek   Economic Issues        02/12/2014
Georgia
        Atlanta        Lack of Transit        02/12/2014
                       Traffic                02/12/2014
        Cummings       Economic Issues        12/11/2014
```

I like to use Jinja2 and create a template for the output of this data. My problem is that I am not sure of the best way to structure this data to then hand over to the template.

Should I create a dictionary of States with each City, Issue and Date information being a list? Should it just be a list of lists? I am very confused on what the data structure should look like so I can easily iterate within a Jinja2 template.

Comment: Jinja2 shouldn't be the driver for your decision whether to go with lists or dictionaries — it can work with equal ease with either.

Comment: @lanzz This is a good point and of course you are right. I am just not sure of the best/most common way to structure the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group your sequence in the template using the [`groupby()` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#groupby):

```
<table>
{% for state in csvrows|groupby('State') %}
    <tr><td rowspan="4">{{ state.grouper }}</td></tr>
    {% for city in state.list|groupby('City') %}
        {% for row in city.list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{% if loop.first %}{{ row.City }}{% endif %}</td>
                <td>{{ row.Issue }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.Date }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

The `groupby()` filter produces group objects, each with `list` and `grouper` attributes. The latter is the value on which the group was built (so the `State` value in the outer loop, `City` in the next loop), and the `.list` attribute is the sequence of values that all have the same `State` or `City` value.

All you then need to produce is a sequence of dictionaries; the `groupby()` filter will even sort your data for you to. Just pass in a `csv.DictReader()` object to Jinja2 and you are all set.

The `groupby()` filter in Jinja works almost exactly like the [`itertools.groupby()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), with which you could produce the same desired output with a few print statements:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> state_key = itemgetter('State')
>>> for state, cities in groupby(sorted(rows, key=state_key), state_key):
...     print state
...     city_key = itemgetter('City')
...     for city, group in groupby(sorted(cities, key=city_key), city_key):
...         print '\t', city
...         for row in group:
...             print '\t\t', row['Issue'], row['Date']
... 
Alaska
    Anchorage
        Weather Issues 2/12/14
California
    Los Angeles
        Traffic 12/11/14
Florida
    Lee
        Traffic 2/12/14
    Levy
        Poor Schools 2/12/14
    Miami
        Weather Issues 12/11/14
        Poor Schools 2/12/14
        Economic Issues 2/12/14
        Lack of Transit 2/12/14
    Sarasota
        Economic Issues 2/12/14
Georgia
    Athens
        Traffic 12/11/14
    Atlanta
        Lack of Transit 2/12/14
        Traffic 2/12/14
    Cummings
        Economic Issues 12/11/14
        Poor Schools 12/11/14
Michigan
    Battle Creek
        Economic Issues 2/12/14
    Detroit
        Economic Issues 12/11/14
        Poor Schools 12/11/14
```

This was produced directly from your sample CSV data; the filter also applies sorting, just like the python sample above.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. In line 11 of your template sample I think you need to have `{% endfor %}`. Should I just be passing a `csv.DictReader` to the `template.redner()`?

Comment: @ajt: yes, just pass in the `DictReader()` object. Template tag corrected, sorry about that.

Comment: Martijn: That is giving me the error `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required`. I appreciate all of your help.

Comment: @ajt: I just took a peek at the `groupby()` filter source and I see that it also sorts the input for you (something that the documentation may need to mention).

Comment: @ajt: Where in your code are you updating dictionaries? That is an exception thrown by `dict.update()`, nothing in my sample code does dictionary updating.

Comment: Here is the full error: `(reports)ajts-hd-mbp:reports ajt$ python ./martijn.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./martijn.py", line 14, in <module>
    print template.render(csvrows)
  File "/Users/ajt/.virtualenvs/reports/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 964, in render
    vars = dict(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required`

Comment: You need to pass the rows in as a keyword argument: `template.render(csvrows=csvrows)`, or pass in a dictionary with key-value pairs like `template.render({'csvrows': csvrows})`. See http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Template.render